# How to use ajax to show php in a modal pop up

Tags: php, html, jquery

hello there :) Im trying to figure out how i can grab some content via ajax in an jquery script im using. Im trying to customize this script to suit my needs, its pretty straight forwrd:

```
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
 var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
 var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

 //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
 var query= popURL.split('?');
 var dim= query[1].split('&');
 var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

 //Fade in the Popup and add close button
 jQuery('#' + popID).fadeIn(200).css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) });


 //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding
 var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
 var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

 //Apply Margin to Popup
 jQuery('#' + popID).css({
     'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
     'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
 });

 //Fade in Background
 $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
 $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) IE

 return false;


});

 //Close Popups and Fade Layer
 $('a.close, #fade, .cancel').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
     $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
         $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
      $('form').clearForm();
 });
     return false;
 });
```

It's calling a div which is hidden. i woukd like to just call a php file, which holds all of the contents instead. this is what the html looks like:

```
<a href="#?w=480" rel="whatever" class="poplight"><input type="button" class="button" value="update"/></a>
```

any ideas? Thanks ahead of time :)

Ok, I tried jQuery UI's dialog...and i must say, It's kinda frustrating...
i know it's difficult to follow someones elses coding, but i actually can tweak pretty much everything except how to use this code to fetch data and show it in the pop up since the href is calling the modal size, and not any actual content

so im back to this one lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use jquery ui's [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) instead(good code quality). Then you get content via [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: The funny thing is, yeah, i could. I'm already loading the library via google for some other use. I could kill two birds with one stone. I'll still have to get familiar with using $.get() though, but thanks for reminding me of that :P

Comment: $.get has enough examples to get you started. Using $.get() is really easy!

Comment: @Sin, I would answer your question but since you are already loading jQueryUI then it's better to use it, upvoted.

Comment: Cool, thanks alot. So, the only thing i'll be changing is my framework right? well, my script. The CSS and content can remain the same right?

Comment: You could choose one of the many available themes. I like the standard theme. Or I believe you can create a theme by using http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/