# How to retrieve content via .load() or $.get() with this line

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

hello :) I posted a question a day or two ago about how to retrieve php via ajax method in this modal I was using. I kinda found out the right way to go about it, but there's still something I'm not doing right (obviously lol) Here's the section thats giving me the issues:

```
   jQuery('div that holds content').fadeIn(200).css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) });
    $('').load('/something/somewhere/this #content');
```

So, im using safari, and a local server (mamp), when I check activity in my browser, it shows that it is loading the content with every click, AND the pop up pops up, but no content. When I simply retrieve content via hidden div, ofcourse, i get it. This is what I'm trying to avoid. right now I have that div in my footer stashed as hidden. I'd rather just make a call when its needed, instead of loading it every single time a page is accessed.

you can go here to see the whole script i posted in my last question:
[How to use ajax to show php in a modal pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482786/how-to-use-ajax-to-show-php-in-a-modal-pop-up)

Anyone have any idea? I read that `.load()` has the ability to grab specific content from a request, but im not sure the major difference between that and `$.get()` I've tried both, and I get the same results. Im using wordpress, and wordpress's ajax requests run smooth as ever, so I know its not a local problem, i'ts my coding lol

Ok....Im done typing :)

Comment: Post the source at `/something/somewhere/this`.  You must have an element with the `id` content.

Comment: is the `#content` the div where you want the content of the second php results displayed? or is that a element in the php results that you want to be displayed on your page? lol lol

Comment: could you explain that to me? sorry I'm not sure what you mean. You mean like `/website/members/ #content`? and `members` has that particular div ?

Comment: the `the div that holds content` is where i want the content to be displayed. the php file post.php has a div wrapped around everything i want to show up in the popup called `#content`

Comment: @Sin, I assume `post.php` is `/something/somewhere/this`.  Post the HTML it generates.

Comment: @matthew right! so how do i post the html? and will it effect the php within that div? it's a form

Comment: @Sin, there are many ways.  One of the easiest is to use the Net pane of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Right-click the correct request, then select Copy Response Body.

Comment: ok, i'll switch to FF to see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work, there must be a URL at your site, `/something/somewhere/this`.  That page needs to contain an element with an id `content`.

See "Loading Page Fragments" at the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation

Comment: Ok, so it needs to be a active page? like, not just a created php file that i saved to a directory? i know it sounds confusing, but I created the page in wordpress to see. if you visit the url, it shows the page, then I went back to the code and i still get a popup, but not the content.

Comment: If it works when you visit the file directory, probably the `#content` selector is wrong.  Make sure it's `id="content"`, not `id="#content"`.

Comment: no it's `id="content"` its `#content` in the jquery though...its been bugging me, cause i know this pop up can be extended to grab content via ajax argh! lol